# How can i switch from BIP32 to BIP44 using bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoinj, bip32-hd-wallets, bip44

i am working on a wallet that is using BIP32 for creating Accounts, addresses, xpub, public keys, transaction and etc. but now i want to switch from BIP32 to BIP 44. how can i do this using bitcoinj i also study [this](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), but there is nothing related to implementation. All i need to know that how can i implement BIP44 using bitcoinj and what is specific changes i have to do.Do i have to change all the hierarchy, if yes, then how can do this

Answer (score 0):

Checkout bitcoinj master branch

Discussion https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/pull/1341

```
    Wallet walletBip39 = Wallet.fromSeed(params, seed);
    System.out.println(walletBip39);

    Wallet walletBip44 = Wallet.fromSeed(params, seed, Script.ScriptType.P2PKH, ImmutableList.of(new ChildNumber(44, true), new ChildNumber(0, true), ChildNumber.ZERO_HARDENED, ChildNumber.ZERO));
    System.out.println(walletBip44);
```