# Bitcoinj Standard

Tags: bitcoinj, android

I'm using bitcoinj for transferring bitcoin.

I don't know which standard bitcoinj supports?
Bip32, Bip39, or Bip44

Please help who knows the answer.

Also I want convert bitcoinj standard to Bip44.

How can I do that?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69928/how-can-i-switch-from-bip32-to-bip44-using-bitcoinj

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it supports all of the above, see documentation: https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.14.7/:

1. **BIP32** - `Class HDKeyDerivation`: Implementation of the BIP 32 deterministic wallet child key generation algorithm.
2. **BIP39** - `Class MnemonicCode`: A MnemonicCode object may be used to convert between binary seed values and lists of words per the BIP 39 specification
3. **BIP44** - `Class DeterministicKeyChain`: see `BIP44_ACCOUNT_ZERO_PATH`