# Is there a way to import bitcoin wallet into BitcoinJ?

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I tried to create bitcoin wallet that could be available as from BitcoinJ as from standart desktop wallet client (Bitcoin.com client e.g.) but it seems that I don't get something important.

I exported the wallet from desktop client which looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd5Xa.png).
After decrypting it with https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/demo/, I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT4Hs.png).

The problem is the Wallet.class methods to import wallets are all eventually have seed creation time as a parameter, which is not stated in exported version of the wallet (setting it randomly doesn't help).

So basically I need any options to transform this exported data into working BitcoinJ wallet.
Any help or advices would be gratelly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `DeterministicHierarchy.BIP32_STANDARDISATION_TIME_SECS` if you want to use it as a normal BIP 32 wallet. The [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048256) that you have should do the rest.

Comment: I tried the method described on the link, but got the wallet with 0 balance.(send some btc to the wallet in desktop client for test). Thought that it's related to BIP32 hierarchy used by bitcoinj (desktop wallet has BIP44). Tried to create wallet with BIP44 following the example given [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69928/how-can-i-switch-from-bip32-to-bip44-using-bitcoinj) but that changed nothing